# Amazon API - get product detail

Tags: rest, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to get information from Amazon Product page (more than 50 parameters: Meta description, Meta title, Meta keywords, Item name, Brand, Price, List price(N), In stock, Seller type, Main category name, First sub category name, First sub category node Id etc).

I look at Amazon's API and see only method http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html
which returns some parameters. Does Amazon have API to get detail data?

Comment: Have you tried ItemSearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the information available on Amazon API is rather limited. You can not get all the data from the API you see on a product page on Amazon.com. Anyway, the API offers several response groups, such as [Large](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Large.html). Take a look at that (and the other response groups), you might be able to fetch just enough data for your needs.

The BrowseNodes response group returns the browse nodes (categories) of the product, with the first returned element being the last child category. So if you want the root category, you'll need to loop through the returned BrowseNodes object to get to the root. The "*IsCategoryRoot*" response element is particularly helpful, it identifies the root browse node once you get that far down the tree.